# Application Menu not rendered in WebSphere Portal 5.1 in IE8

Tags: menu, internet-explorer-8, rendering, websphere-portal

I have a Portal application running on WebSphere Portal 5.1. The Navigation Menu appears fine in IE6 browser. If I see the same application in IE8 Browser the menu are not rendered. All I get is "New Page" and "New Label"  [image: Menu Rendering]. 
    Is this a problem with WebSphere Portal 5.1 or Am I missing some setting in the Server ?

Thanks,
SKR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a issue with WebSphere Portal 5.1 and IE8. Try deploying the application in WebSphere Portal 6 or above and check the application. You should get the menu in it.